# How to do a sign-up and log-in page like those of instagram with html and twitter-bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a sign-up and log-in page like those of Instagram. I encounter difficulties in horizontal and centre alignment of the element and espacially to put the small horizontal bar. I have already spent a day on it, I need help please.

Here is my HTML and CSS code :

```
<body>
        <div id="bloc_page">
           <div id="formulaire">
             <div id="titre">
                Gestion TP-TD
             </div>
              <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input  class="form-control" placeholder="Numéro de téléphone, @email ou nom utilisateur" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe" type="password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Sign In</button>
                </div>
              </form>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="bloc_page">
            <div id="lien"> Vous n'avez pas de compte? <a href="#">S'inscrire</a> </div>
        </div>

    </body>
```

```
#bloc_page {

    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 37%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 3%;
    padding-bottom: 5px;    
}

#titre {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2.0em;
}

#lien {
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

And i get this :
[image]

here is for instagram :
[image]

Comment: You have two bloc_page ids. ID should not be repeated on the same page. Give one another name

Comment: It's ok. that's fix many of my problems. How i do for put the two horizontals bars which are symetrics at "Or" ? look at instagram's page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS solution:

For `#titre` & `#lien`, to align them vertically, you can try using the `line-height` property.

To align `#lien` horizontally, wrap the content in a `<p>` tag and set the `text-align: center;` property.

--

For the horizontal lines you can use the `<hr>` tag.

```css
hr {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

p {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<hr/>
<p>OR</p>
<hr/>
```

I'd recommend looking into the bootstrap grid system either way though.

Comment: thanks. it's more better. now, how i can do for put the two horizontals bars which are symetrics at "Or" ? look at instagram's page.

Comment: @fogangfokoa Edited my comment, this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
    hr{
       border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
       }

    .between_horizontal_lines{
      text-align: center;
      margin:0; 
      font-size: 11px;
      }

    .or{
        padding-top:10px;
        }
```

If you are using Bootstrap 3

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-5">
         <hr> 
     </div>

     <div class="col-xs-2 or">
        <p class="between_horizontal_lines">OR</p>
     </div> 

     <div class="col-xs-5">
         <hr>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Bootstrap 4

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-5">
         <hr> 
     </div>

     <div class="col-sm-2 or">
        <p class="between_horizontal_lines">OR</p>
     </div> 

     <div class="col-sm-5">
         <hr>
     </div>
 </div>
```

I tested on both and found that 4 didn't recognize the xs class

Answer (score 0):

use bootstrap grid system

```
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
</div>
```

Comment: With this method, i had the weird results. It's for this reason that i use more CSS